# jQuery conflicting with other libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing trouble in jQuery implementation,
my jQuery code have been conflicted in this.
I am using 'latest.pack.js' with 'source.js' and 'prototype.js'.

Above mentioned all jQuery not working reason may be conflicting and jQuery no conflicting code is also not working there .
So Please help me soon as possible

Link are :
http://prototypejs.org/assets/2009/8/31/prototype.js

Answer (score 5):

If at all possible, do yourself the favour and use one JavaScript library only.

- Loading two full-blown libraries can be resource-heavy, especially if they both walk through the entire DOM to initialize some widgets or something.
- Even with `noConflict` it is possible for problems to occur. Libraries use different internal methods to manipulate events and DOM nodes. There is the possibility of subtle bugs that `noConflict` is unable to prevent.
- You will have two syntaxes and philosophies to work with.
- You will have two libraries to update and check dependencies for.

Pick one, and select your plugins and widgets based on that one library.

Comment: If you're unsure which one  to go with - I think it's safe to say that jQuery has become the more popular and better supported one between the two. There's a jQuery plugin for pretty much every purpose under the sun.

Comment: I was going to suggest that ... but I always get stamped on for "pushing jQuery" !!!

Comment: @Manse that's why I hid the recommendation in a comment ;) although let's face it - jQuery has won the war. There's no denying it any more. (and that's coming from a former enthusiastic Prototype.JS user.)

Answer (score 3):

Lots of libraries use the `$` symbol .. you need to use the [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) jQuery method like so :

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// then your jQuery code ... for example
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

or you could use a different variable for jQuery :

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function($) {
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simple solution is to wrap your JQuery code with an anonymous function:

```
(function($) {
   // your jQuery code
   $('#foo');
})(jQuery);
```

Though I would recommend to only use one library if possible. Multiple libraries clutter the code, increase the page load time and can produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `noConflict` method.
Another way to get rid of the conflict would be to separate your jquery code from the other libs :

```
(function($){
    //jquery code here  
    // $ represents jQuery in this block 
    alert($ === jQuery);     
})(jQuery); 
// outside the block, $ is set to the other libs that overwrite this variable
alert($ === jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

“Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery’s case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If we need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict():"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
 // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery documentation site has a link in main menu **"Using jQuery With Other Libraries"** with full instructions on implementing noConflict()

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries