# prototype Lightbox doesn't work with jquery code

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, prototypejs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="skin/lightbox.css" media="screen,projection" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/lightbox.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
              url: "getResult.php",

              success: function(result){

              var output = '<tr><td>Name</td>\n\
                                <td>Type</td>\n\
                                <td>Data</td>\n\
                                <td>Detail</td></tr>';
               $.each(result, function(i, result){

               output += '<tr><td>' +  result.sensorName + '</td><td>' +
                      result.sensorType + '</td><td>' +
                      result.data + '</td><td><a href="lightBox.php" class="lbOn">view</a></td></tr>';   
                      //Naming class="lbOn" can trigger Lightbox function
               });

               $("#insideTable").html(output);

        }, dataType: "json"});
    }, 2000);
});

</script>


<table border="1" id="insideTable" width="100%">

</table>
```

The Lightbox in the above code doesn't work. (see Lightbox example I'm using: http://particletree.com/examples/lightbox/).
I think it's probablly conflict with the existing Jquery code.

Then I added jQuery.noConflict(); and amended $ to Jquery which even prevent the exist Jq code working.

Is there anyone can help me? Many thanks!

Comment: What errors, if any, does the console report?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery conflicting with other libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683110/jquery-conflicting-with-other-libraries)

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, here is console report: ($(parentElement) || document.body).getElementsByTagName is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Quoting myself from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683110/jquery-conflicting-with-other-libraries/9683225#9683225)....

If at all possible, do yourself the favour and use one JavaScript library only.

- Loading two full-blown libraries can be resource-heavy, especially if they both walk through the entire DOM to initialize some widgets or something.
- Even with `noConflict` it is possible for problems to occur. Libraries use different internal methods to manipulate events and DOM nodes. There is the possibility of subtle bugs that `noConflict` is unable to prevent.
- You will have two syntaxes and philosophies to work with.
- You will have two libraries to update and check dependencies for.

Pick one, and select your plugins and widgets based on that one library.

Answer (score -1):

You should run jQuery in noConflict mode. Use `jQuery.noConflict()` after you added the jQuery script tag. In your code you have to change `$` to `jQuery` where jQuery is used

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Or use fancybox for jQuery insteed ;-)